# How can we display html field based on the data in collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, jenkins, meteor-blaze

I'm new to meteor, I want to retrieve the jenkins job and store that job detail with parameters inside mongoDB collection and then display different fields like text box, check button for that data in collection.
**My Job collection**

```
 db.jobs.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a15bc45145a3789cb3b97eb"),
    "platform" : "xyz",
    "job_name" : "http://123.123.123.123:111/jobs",
    "a" : 0,
    "b" : 0,
    "c" : 0,
    "d" : 0,
    "e" : 0,
}
```

As you can see i have this data in collection, for "job_name","platform" i want to get the text box and for other parameter i want check boxes.
There may be many jobs and each should have the above property.
**joblist.html**

```
<template name="jobs">
 <div id="listjobs">
  {{#each jobs}}
    ????how can i do it????
  {{/each}}
 </div>
</template>
```

I have not written much in the js part.Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#each` block is just a wrapper for `for each` where the current document becomes `this` within this block. You can then use the data either with `this` (as in my example below) or just referenced by the property name. More on this read [here in the Blaze documentation](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Each).

Just as a preview:

```html
<template name="jobs">
 <div id="listjobs">
  {{#each jobs}}
     <div>: {{this.job_name}}</div>
     <form id="form_{{this._id}}">
        <textarea name="platform">{{this.platform}}</textarea>
        <textarea name="job_name">{{this.job_name}}</textarea>
        <input type="checkbox" name="a">{{this.a}}
        <input type="checkbox" name="b">{{this.b}}
        <input type="checkbox" name="c">{{this.c}}
        <input type="checkbox" name="d">{{this.d}}
        <input type="checkbox" name="e">{{this.e}}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
  {{/each}}
 </div>
</template>
```

note that you can use the context even in the attributes, as used in the form id. If you want your checkbox have initial values checked you need to make it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="e" checked="{{this.e}}">{{this.e}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the returned value for jobs is an object looks like this

```
{
    "job": "job1",
    "job": "job2"
}
```

Just use it

```
<form id="demo">
    {# for data in jobs #}
    <div id="listjobs">
        <input type="checkbox">{{ data.job }}
    </div>
    {# endfor #}
</form>
```